# Create a function as input one of a pandas column (variable) to create plots

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, plot

I have a dataframe with multiple columns and so variables.
I would like to create a function to apply on some variables of the dataframe to create some displots representing mean, median and mode.
I found a great code to do so as you will see after.

My problem is that I would like to automatize the displot creation and not copy paste it everytime I want to create a plot on an another variable and I am not sure how to do this.

Here is the code (and i would like to change the variable 'fat_100g' easily) :

```
f, (ax_box, ax_hist) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, gridspec_kw= {"height_ratios": (0.2, 1)})
mean=df['fat_100g'].mean()
median=df['fat_100g'].median()
mode=df['fat_100g'].mode().to_numpy()[0]

sns.boxplot(df["fat_100g"], ax=ax_box)
ax_box.axvline(mean, color='r', linestyle='--')
ax_box.axvline(median, color='g', linestyle='-')
ax_box.axvline(mode, color='b', linestyle='-')

sns.distplot(df["fat_100g"], ax=ax_hist)
ax_hist.axvline(mean, color='r', linestyle='--')
ax_hist.axvline(median, color='g', linestyle='-')
ax_hist.axvline(mode, color='b', linestyle='-')

plt.legend({'Mean':mean,'Median':median,'Mode':mode})

ax_box.set(xlabel='')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a variable, call it key=(whatever you want) and then use:

```
mean=df[key].mean()
```

If you'd like to loop through all of this:

```
for key in list(df.columns):
    ##Do the plotting code; pay attention to not overwriting axes if you want to do this, maybe make ax a list and loop through the list using ax[ind] and add to the ind every loop?
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)